# Enabling / Disabling Features in a Laravel App

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, design-patterns, laravel-4

I'm building a Laravel app, which has a number of various features. I want to be able to enable or disable them depending on a particular domain's requirement. Currently, I have in my config a series of flags such as:

```
'is_feature_1_enabled' => true,
'is_feature_2_enabled' => false,
```

... and so on.

Then in my controllers and views, I check those config values to see whether or not I should be displaying something, allowing certain actions, etc. My app is starting to get polluted with these kinds of checks everywhere.

**Is there a best practice method of managing features in a Laravel app?**

Comment: disable routes instead of controller? or using middleware maybe

Comment: Feature !== page.

Comment: amybe this? https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-feature

Comment: Might actually be a solution. Want to make your comment into an answer?

Comment: mh no problem, is not an answer, the important is that it might helps you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is technically called feature flags - https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html

depends on your requirements, flags in config/database, rollout, etc...

But it's basically if's in code and cannot be clean.

Laravel packages:

https://github.com/alfred-nutile-inc/laravel-feature-flag

https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-feature

Some services:

https://launchdarkly.com/

https://bullet-train.io/

https://configcat.com/

Also look at https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/optimize/ for frontend.

Comment: You can find a sample laravel project with feature flagging here: https://github.com/configcat/php-sdk/tree/master/samples/laravel

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same problem when I tried to implement multiple hotel providers.

What I did was using service container.

**first** you  will create class for each domain With his features:

- like Doman1.php ,Domain2.php
- then inside each one of those you will add your logic.

**then** you gonna use binding in your app service provider to bind the domain with class to use.

```
$this->app->bind('Domain1',function (){
       return new Domain1();
    });
    $this->app->bind('Domain2',function (){
        return new Domain2();
    });
```

**Note** you can use general class that holds the features goes with all domains then use that general class in your classes

Finally in your controller you can check your domain then to use the class you gonna use

```
    app(url('/'))->methodName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting case you have here. It might be interesting to look into a `Feature` interface or abstract class that contains a few methods you generally need.

```
interface Feature
{
    public function isEnabled(): bool;

    public function render(): string;

    // Not entirely sure if this would be a best practice but the idea is to be
    // able to call $feature->execute(...) on any feature.
    public function execute(...);

    ...
}
```

You could even devide these into `ExecutableFeature` and `RenderableFeature`.

Further on some kind of factory class could be made to make life easier.

```
// Call class factory.
Feature::make('some_feature')->render();
...->isEnabled();

// Make helper method.
feature('some_feature')->render();

// Make a blade directives.
@feature('some_feature')
@featureEnabled('some_feature')
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are hard coding things based on config values to enable or disable certain features. I recommend you to control things based on named routes rather than config value.

1. Group all the route as a whole or by feature wise.
2. Define name for all routes
3. Control the enable/disable activity by route name and record in database
4. Use Laravel middleware to check whether a particular feature is enabled or disabled by getting the current route name from request object and matching it with the database..

so you will not have the same conditions repeating every where and bloat your code..
here is a sample code show you how to retrieve all routes, and you can match the route group name to further process to match your situation.

```
Route::get('routes', function() {
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

echo "<table >";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>HTTP Method</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Route</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='80%'><h4>Corresponding Action</h4></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getMethods()[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getPath() . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getName() . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
});
```

and here is a sample middleware handler where you can check whether a particular feature is active by matching with what you have already stored in your database..

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Helper::isDisabled($request->route()->getName())){
             abort(403,'This feature is disabled.');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: This assumes that the features equates to pages on the site, right? That's not the case. A feature could be some snippet within a page (e.g. a Google Map will display in the sidebar), or some sort of functionality (e.g. users can export some data).

Comment: you are correct, however do you mean some blocks that get displayed on different pages? what are you constraints to display it? specific page wise or on all pages you display it

Comment: The features can be an entire page, or just a portion of a page, or just some functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those features are only needed for HTTP requests.

I would create a default `Features` base class with all the default flags:

```
Class Features {
    // Defaults
    protected $feature1_enabled = true;
    protected $feature2_enabled = true;

    public function isFeature1Enabled(): bool
    {
        return $this->feature1_enabled;
    }

    public function isFeature2Enabled(): bool
    {
        return $this->feature2_enabled;
    }
}
```

Then I would extend that class for each Domain and set the overrides that are needed for that domain:

```
Class Domain1 extends Features {
    // override
    protected $feature1_enabled = false;
}
```

Then create a Middleware to bind the Features Class to the container:

```
class AssignFeatureByDomain
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
            case 'domain1':
                app()->bind(Features::class, Domain1::class);
                break;
            default:
                abort(401, 'Domain rejected');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to attach this middleware to your routes: to a group or for each route.

After this you can TypeHint your Features class in your controllers:

```
public function index(Request $request, Features $features)
{
    if ($features->isFeature1Enabled()) {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is great with this, you can even store your features in db, and create a relation between the domain.

I would recommend to use Gates and Policies, which will give you better control in your controllers and blade templates. This means you register the gates from your db or hard code them.

For example if you have export products feature with a button in your system and you want to make that feature available to some users you can register gates with business logic.

```
//Only admins can export products
Gate::define('export-products', function ($user) {
    return $user->isAdmin;
});
```

Then you can do the following in the controllers

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Export products
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  Post  $post
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function export(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('export-products');

        // The current user can export products
    }
}
```

Here is an example for your blade templates:

```
@can('export-products', $post)
    <!-- The Current User Can export products -->
@endcan

@cannot('export-products')
    <!-- The Current User Can't export products -->
@endcannot
```

more information available at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my case was creating a new table on the database, you could call it `Domains` for instance.

Add all the specific features, those which could be shown on some domains but not in the rest, as columns for that table as bit for boolean values. Like, in my case, `allow_multiple_bookings`, `use_company_card`... whatever.

Then, consider creating a class `Domain` and its respective repository, and just ask these values on your code, trying to push as much as possible that logic into your domain (your model, application services, etc).

For instance, I would not do the check on the controller method for `RequestBooking` if the domain which is requesting a booking can request only one or more.

Instead I do it on a `RequestBookingValidatorService` which can check if the booking datetime has passed, the user has an enabled credit card, ... or the Domain which this action comes from is allowed to request more than one booking (and then if it already has any).

This adds the convenience of readability, as you have pushed this decision to your application services. Also, I find that whenever I need a new feature I can use Laravel (or Symfony) migrations to add that feature on the table and I could even update its rows (your domains) with the values I want on the same commit I coded.